# best way to handle complex mysql search and measure how good of a match each result is

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, search

Sorry for the long title but couldn't think of a good way to put it really - i'm currently working on a large web app project and one of the main features is the detailed search, without saying too much about the project it is used to find business related deals - the search function is spread over 3 pages currently and offers pretty much every option you'd want if you were in the industry...

But the problem i've got now is that is a lot of fields and so when it comes to searching for matches in the db i don't really know the best way forward i don't think a standard mysql like is going to cut it here also i need to be able figure out how much of a fit (good match) each result is and then display that in the results (search result 1 is a 90% fit etc)

Does anyone know which is the best way to tackle this ? i know there are external search engines etc out there but don't know anything about them really to make any sort of logical choice...

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding relevance in search is a complex topic that deals with many parameters. The MySQL match() search itself is pretty complex as you can see [here](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_Algorithms#Full-text_Search). Perhaps you could use this score itself as your measure. You can [customize](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) this to some extent.

Another option as you mentioned is to use external search engines, something on the lines of [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). It has all the requirements you are looking for. Its fast, scalable and able to provide customizing options to improve "relevance" for your specific needs.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer i'm just looking into MySQL match now - so far seems like it could be a good fit...